# how to use circular reveal library dependency into pre lollipop version?

Tags: java, android

I'm using the circular reveal library which is running on android 9 API 28 but couldn't run on android 5 API 22 so did any one have a solution?

implementation 'com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.1.0'

Comment: Have you added this in project build.gradle repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
}

Comment: yes i added this also but having same problem